# Alexa flask-ask get the user personal information

Tags: python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

I had setup Alexa skill to use Flask-Ask.
Skill works fine as expected.
Now I need to get the user personal information like name,phone,email,address.So I had used the below code

```
@ask.intent('AskPermission')
def get_permission():
    token=context.System.apiAccessToken
    api_end_point=context.System.apiEndpoint
    request_id=request.requestId
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
               # "X-Amzn-RequestId":request_id,
               "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)}
    body = {
              "version": "1.0",
              "response": {
                "card": {
                  "type": "AskForPermissionsConsent",
                  "permissions": [
                    "alexa::profile:email:read",
                  ]
                }
              }
            }

    permission_result = requests.get('{api_end_point}/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email'.format(api_end_point=api_end_point), json=body, headers=headers)
```

I am getting 403 in response everytime.
I am testing it on alexa simulator.
I had enabled the permission inside the skills like below [image]

So am I doing anything wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Enabling permission in skill configuration means that the skill can ask for a consent from the user to access certain information. In your case, email Id. Once you configure  that permission, the user has to grant access to that particular information. It's just like how you provide permission in Android apps. There are two ways in which a user can grant permission to your skill:

1. Users will have to explicitly grant access to your skill under `Settings` menu of your Alexa skill.
2. You can send a `permission card` to the user for consent.

Before you hit the `apiEndpoint` with the `apiAccessToken` you should have access to that information. Otherwise you would get `403`. So whenever you get `403`, send the user back a `permission card`. And once the user grants you permission, hit the `apiEndpoint` for the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone,who has stuck on the same point.
I was testing it from the alexa simulator.
So to grant the permission you have to 
Go to https://alexa.amazon.in/spa/index.html#cards. This url is not mention in any documentation.

Select Skills (from left menu) => Your skills => All skills
Grant the permission.

Below video has helped me to do this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xfn5kNWbnU

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to pass a body to the api:

```
@ask.intent('AskPermission')
def get_permission():
    """ Retreive User email from alexa user profile api """

    token = context.System.apiAccessToken
    api_end_point = context.System.apiEndpoint
    headers = {
        "Host": "api.amazonalexa.com",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)}

    resp = requests.get('{api_end_point}/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email'.format(api_end_point=api_end_point),headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return resp.json()
    return resp
```